# Multi-Step Form Require Certain Fields To Go to Next Step

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to require certain fields before moving to the next page of fields to break up a longer form. In this example i just want email, not first or last to be required before moving to the next set of fields. I cannot get the error message to show that i want and have been working off of this example: [Required attribute in multi step form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134980/required-attribute-in-multi-step-form).

Thank you for any help.

```js
function checkValue() {
        var name = document.getElementById("email");
        if(email.value === "") {
          var att = document.createAttribute("required");
          name.setAttributeNode(att);
        }
    }
```

```html
<form>
<div class="tab">Personal Information
  <p><input placeholder="First name" name="first" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  <p><input placeholder="Last name" ></p>
<p><input placeholder="Email" required="required" id="email" name="email" required="required" ></p>
</div>

<div style="overflow:auto;">
  <div style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn">Previous</button>
    <button type="button"  id="nextBtn" style="color:#ffffff" onclick="checkValue();" >Next</button>
  </div>
</div>



</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the type on the next button

```js
function checkValue() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
      
        if(email.value === "") {
         
          var att = document.createAttribute("required");
          email.setAttributeNode(att);
        }
    }
```

```html
<form>
<div class="tab">Personal Information
  <p><input placeholder="First name" name="first" oninput="this.className = ''"></p>
  <p><input placeholder="Last name" ></p> 
<p><input placeholder="Email"  id="email" name="email"  ></p>
</div>
<div style="overflow:auto;">
  <div style="float:right;">
    <button type="button" id="prevBtn">Previous</button>
    <button   id="nextBtn" style="color:#ffffff" onclick="checkValue();" >Next</button>
  </div>
</div>



</form>
```